# System.setProperty method and proxy settings

Tags: java, proxy

I use proxy in my java app.I set the proxy settings from code in my java app.

```
  System.setProperty("https.proxyHost",myproxy);
  System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","80");
```

So I want to know that if that proxy settings affect all the other applications in the server or only that app(which I set proxy settings in it).

I don't want to affect other applications proxy settings in the server.

Comment: `System.setProperty` is **evil**. Never call this method except in test cases. It affects the entire JVM.